# Why does x>> in vim have another indent than when im pressing tab?

Tags: linux, vim

When im using the vim command 4>> in vim to indent four lines of code vim indents the lines with 8 spaces, but if i indent these lines manually but pressing tab in front of them they are indented with 4 spaces which is what i have configured in my .vimrc file. It seems like the 4>> command is somehow bypassing my configuration..does someone know why this is happening..

Also, does someone know if there is a way to ident the other way as well and not just indent to the right but also to the left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hitting TAB indents to the next multiple of the `tabstop` value.

Using `>>` indents by the value of the `shiftwidth` variable.

> Also, does someone know if there is a way to ident the other way as well and not just indent to the right but also to the left.

`<<` is the opposite of `>>`

Comment: nice, that worked. both answers were good but since you answered both of my questions ill give you the correct answer mark

Answer (score 3):

You seem to have inconsistent values of `'shiftwidth'` (which governs the `>>` behavior and seems to be `8` in your case) and `'tabstop'` / `'softtabstop'` (which control the amount of spaces inserted when pressing Tab in insert mode; either `8/4` or `4/4` or `4/0` in your case).

Comment: also there is useful information about how to use tabs in vim when you read `:h 'ts'`